# Excel VBAで作成したPDFのサイズを(VBAで)統一したい

Tags: vba, pdf

ExcelシートのPDF化をVBAで実装したのですが、ページによってサイズが統一されていない状況になっています。

原因は下記リンクと同じ状況のようです。

[ExcelからPDFを作成すると、ページのサイズがまちまち](http://donboolacoo.blog92.fc2.com/blog-entry-2047.html)

出力したPDFをAcrobatで開き、PDFPrinterで再PDF化しているようなのですが、この流れをすべてVBA上で行いたいと考えています。

上記案ではなくてもPDFのサイズの統一ができればそれでも問題ありません。

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Excelの印刷設定はシート毎にあります。複数のシートを選択していても現在のシートにしか反映されなかったかと思います。ですので、シート毎に印刷設定を行ってから、複数シートを選択し印刷してください。

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。少し調査を進めたところ、印刷設定のプリンタに「PDFCreator」を選択しているときにのみ発生していました。他のプリンタを選択した状態でPDF出力を実行した場合は今回のようなページごとにサイズが異なる現象は発生しませんでした。

Answer (score -1):

便利で使いやすいコンポーネントをおすすめします、無料で使用できるSpire.XLS for .NETを通して、ExcelドキュメントをPDFに簡単に変換できます。

詳細な手順について、こちらの記事を参照してください：
https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Conversion/Convert-worksheet-to-PDF-in-C-VB.NET.html